# PythonAnywhere: Tkinter.py error when trying to use easygui module

Tags: python, bash, tkinter, pythonanywhere

My son is trying to execute a small program using pythonAnywhere.

```
import random, easygui
secret = random.randint(1,99)
guess = 0
tries = 0
easygui.msgbox ("AHOY! I'm the Dread Pirate Roberts, and I have a    secret!\n"
"It is a number from 1 to 99. I'll give ye 6 tries.")
while guess != secret and tries < 6:
    guess = easygui.integerbox ("What's yer guess, matey?")
    if not guess: break
    if guess < secret:
        easygui.msgbox (str(guess) + "is too low, ye scurvy dog!")
    elif guess > secret:
        easygui.msgbox (str(guess) + "is too high, landlubber!" )
    tries = tries + 1
if guess == secret:
    easygui.msgbox ("Avast! Ye got it! Found me secret, ye did!" )
else:
    easygui.msgbox ("No more guesses! The number was" + str(secret))
```

When running the code from the bash console, the follow error gets thrown:

```
File "NumGuess.py", line 6, in <module>
    It is a number from 1 to 99. I'll give ye 6 tries.""")
  File "/home/016646/.local/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/easygui/boxes/derived_boxes.py", line 216, in msgbox
    cancel_choice=ok_button)
  File "/home/016646/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/easygui/boxes/base_boxes.py", line 66, in buttonbox
    boxRoot = Tk()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1767, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className,     interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

The module easygui was installed using pip install --user easygui, as suggested on PythonAnywhere's forums.

Since PA is a web-based environment, I'm not sure if there is some extra nuance. There are some suggestions online regarding this error when ssh'ing into a system. However, PA is accessed via web login, so that might not apply.

Answer (score 5):

Tkinter (and thus, easygui) requires an actual screen to draw on. The error is telling you it can't find the screen. Tkinter simply is not designed to run in a web-based environment.

More info at [this pythonanywhere help page on tkinter and other gui libraries](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/TkinterPygameEtc).